# Validate error message styling

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-validate

I am trying to get the jQuery Validate error class to display a certain way, but am having difficulty getting it to work. I am wanting the validation messages to appear directly under my inputs. Right now they appear under my inputs, however the entire input jumps down to the next line.

The inputs set naturally like this:

Name --  Number   --  Email

I want the message to appear like this:

Name --  Number --  Email

Message -- Message -- Message

Right now it is doing:

Name

Message

Number

Message

Email

Message

The HTML looks like this:

```
<form action="" method="POST" id="contact-form1">
                <input type="text" class="contact-input show-input" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name *">
                <input type="text" class="contact-input show-input" name="number" id="number" placeholder="Phone Number *">
                <input type="text" class="contact-input show-input" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email *">
                <input type="text" class="contact-input hidden-input" placeholder="Company Name">
                <input type="text" class="contact-input hidden-input" placeholder="Title">
                <input type="text" class="contact-input hidden-input" placeholder="Referral">
                <textarea class="contact-message" rows="10" name="message" id="message" placeholder="Your Message*"></textarea>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="contact-submit">
            </form>
```

I tried wrapping divs around each input, but this put each input on a new line in a block format.

Here is a fiddle to see what this is doing:  [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b84eyynq/)

What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE:

```
 submitHandler: function(form) {

        var name = $("#name").val();
        var number = $("#number").val();
        var email = $("#email").val();
        var message = $("#message").val();
        /*var company_name = $("#company_name");
        var title = $("#title");
        var referral = $("#referral");*/
        //var targeted_popup_class = jQuery(this).attr('data-popup-open');

        $.ajax({
          url: "map-send.php",
          type: "POST",
          data: {
            "name": name,
            "number": number,
            "email": email,
            "message": message
            /*"company_name": company_name,
            "title": title,
            "referral": referral*/
          },
          success: function(data) {
```

In the code above you will see items commented out. These are the non-validated items. For some reason when I take away the comment tags my page dies. No errors, it just freezes when I submit the page. I tried taking the variables outside of the validate tags, but it still did not help. Do you know why this would kill the page?

Comment: FYI on your edit:  you're missing `.val()` on the three commented out items.  However, as stated in a comment on my answer, just use jQuery `.serialize()` instead of specifying each value.

Comment: @Sparky I didn't use the `.val()` because I do not want to validate those items. I just want to send the data via ajax. That was a bit of my confusion.

Comment: jQuery `.val()` retrieves the "value".  It has absolutely nothing to do with validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [the documentation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate):

1. You cannot set [the `onfocusout` option](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate#onfocusout) to `true`.  It over-rides the internal function of the plugin thereby breaking it.  It can only be set to `false` to disable this option or an over-riding function.  Otherwise, leave this option out to keep the `onfocusout` behavior, which is active by default.
2. You're missing a `.val()` on some of your input values so you're trying to pass the entire jQuery object instead of just its value.  However, instead of trying to manually specify each value within your `.ajax()` function, use [jQuery `.serialize()`](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) to pass the data string for the whole form.

   ```
   data: $("#contact-form1").serialize(),
   ```

   and anyplace within the `submitHandler` function, you can use the passed `form` argument variable...

   ```
   data: $(form).serialize(),
   ```
3. Use the [`errorElement`](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate#errorelement) and [`errorPlacement`](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate#errorplacement) options to determine how/where the error messages appear in the DOM.

   - `errorElement` defaults to `label` (inline element) and you could change this into a `div` (block-level element) or any element you may need.  The default is shown below as an example.

     ```
     errorElement: 'label', // default
     ```
   - `errorPlacement` defaults to inserting the error message just *after* the input element.  In your case, your structure causes this to wrap, thereby breaking your layout.  If you want the messages to appear someplace else in the DOM, then you need to write a new `errorPlacement` function.  The default is shown below as an example.

     ```
     errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
         error.insertAfter(element); // default
     },
     ```

Your root problem is that **you have not designed your form layout with the error messages in mind**.  You need to start over and make a layout that can accomodate the error message elements in the exact position you desire.  Then these two custom jQuery Validate functions can dynamically create and insert the error message elements in your desired position.

**Proof of concept example**:

HTML

```
<form>
    <div class="input">
        <input type="text" name="name" />
    </div>
    <div class="input">
        <input type="text" name="number" />
    </div>
    ....
```

JavaScript

```
$("#contact-form1").validate({
    errorElement: 'div',
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        error.insertAfter(element);  // default
    },
    rules: { ....
```

DEMO:  https://jsfiddle.net/ng3a9xwz/

---

**EDIT:**

Inspecting the **live DOM** reveals...

```
<form novalidate="novalidate">
    <div class="input">
        <input type="text" name="name" class="error" />
        <div for="name" class="error">Please enter your name</div>
    </div>
    ....
```

`errorElement: 'div'` puts the error message into a `div` and the default `errorPlacement` inserts this new `div` immediately after the `input` element.  Design your layout (CSS & HTML) to properly accommodate these options.  You can use the markup from the live DOM for layout testing purposes.

Comment: Is this `  errorElement: 'div',` saying the error message will be inside of the div the input it wrapped around?

Comment: @Becky, **no**, it's simply saying that a `<div>` will be created to contain each error message instead of the default `<label>` element.   You could use the developer tools in your browser to inspect the live DOM and view these dynamic elements as they're created.  See my edited answer.

Comment: Thank you. I tried this in a new fiddle and it works just like I want it (other than fixing the styling). Two questions (3 if you don't mind). 1. Why is the live DOM showing `novalidate="novalidate"`. Is that the default for the validate plugin (is this making it only validate after the submit was hit?)   2.  If this `error.insertAfter(element);  // default` is default then why does it need entered into the code? 3. See my question update....By the way thanks for helping me with this and the great answer!

Comment: @Becky - 1.  `novalidate` is dynamically added by the plugin to disable HTML 5 validation.  2.  You do NOT need to put `errorPlacement` in your code if you're just wanting the default... I just put it there to demonstrate.  3.  Just lookup and use the jQuery `.serialize()` function instead of specifying each input's value.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score -1):

Try having each input in a div and then all the inputs in a line in a div ,set the overall div to 100% width and the internal div to 100/3 %

Comment: I kind of understand what you mean, but could you please elaborate? Not too sure on the internal div part.